# Get request headers at doGet()

Tags: google-apps-script, request-headers

I want to get the request header when I requested to doGet(). I deployed Web Apps like below.

Condition of Web Apps is

- Execute the app as: is "me".
- Who has access to the app: is "Anyone, even anonymous".

doGet() is

```
function doGet(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

`e` is

```
{
  "parameter": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "contextPath": "",
  "contentLength": -1,
  "queryString": "key=value",
  "parameters": {
    "key": [
      "value"
    ]
  }
}
```

`e` doesn't include the request header. I read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). But there are no information to get it. Perhaps there are no official methods to do. So I am looking for the workarounds. Are there workarounds to get the header?

Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: How are you making the request to the web app with the `doGet(e)` function?  When an HTTPS Request is made, the source of the request can set the headers.  If you were making a GET request with Apps Script, you would use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)`  [Advanced Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Comment: @Sandy Good Thank you for comment. I request to doGet() using curl as a test like ``curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?key=value"``. I can use ``UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)`` too. But I don't know how to get the request header at doGet(e).

Comment: You can see what is in the request parameters with:  `var params = e.parameter; Logger.log('params : ' + params);Logger.log('params : ' + JSON.stringify(params ));`  Once you know the key names in the payload, you can know whether there is a request header in it or not.  If it's not in there, then you can't get it.

Comment: @Sandy Good I couldn't find request header and also other workaround.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I want to pass in apiKey in request header to secure my application

Comment: App Script doGet() and doPost() do not support headers. Check [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)